# NSDateFormatter not parsing date string when in [array sortUsingComparator:] block

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have a Mutable Array called tableContents that is holding parsed XML information. I am trying to sort the items in the array by date. I have a date string from the XML stored in every object in the array. I have tested the format of my NSDateFormatter and it does properly parse the date string EXCEPT for inside the sortUsingComparator: block. Here is my code:

```
    [tableContents sortUsingComparator: ^(NSMutableDictionary *d1, NSMutableDictionary *d2) {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss '+0000'"];

    NSString *date1String = [d1 valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"d1 Date is: %@", date1String);

    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:date1String];
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[d2 valueForKey:@"date"]];

    NSLog(@"date1: %@",date1);
    NSLog(@"date2: %@",date2);

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

date1String logs a string of this format: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 17:30:52 +0000
But then date1 and date2 are both null, I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Does that format work outside of a block?

Comment: And is date1String actually an NSString, or is it an NSDate?

Comment: [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];                               you should use timezone offset z intested of +0000